# Связь в предложениях (БСП / СПП)

Tags: придаточное-предложение, тип-придаточных

> Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце
> XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль, для этого были приглашены
> итальянские мастера.

Может ли часть "для этого были приглашены итальянские мастера" быть придаточным предложением? Если нет, то как оно связано с предыдущим и как эта связь называется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль, **ДЛЯ ЭТОГО** были приглашены итальянские мастера.*

**Это БСП, бессоюзная связь.** ***Для этого*** — анафорическое местоимение, отсылающее к **первой части** предложения. В БСП основным средством связи является **интонация**, а местоимение — это дополнительный  структурный элемент.

**СПП с придаточным присоединительным** выглядит так: *Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль,  ***ДЛЯ ЧЕГО*** были приглашены итальянские мастера.* Для связи используется союзное слово ***для чего***.

**Похожий вариант разбирается  учебнике для вузов**: Кустова  Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского языка, стр. 234, 2005 г. [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

БСП НЕОДНОРОДНОГО СОСТАВА 1. **Распространительно-присоединительное грамматическое значение.** Вторая часть может распространять всю первую часть или одно слово в первой части: *Был, словом, у Понтия Пилата, **за это** я ручаюсь (Б.); Мы заблудились, **этого** я и боялся* (сравним синонимичное СПП с придаточным присоединительным: *Мы заблудились, **чего** я и боялся*).

Comment: ФИПИ любит подкидывать такие задания, где с одной стороны местоименные наречия и другие конструкции, по их мнению, являются союзными словами / союзами, образуя СПП, когда на деле это спорно...

Comment: Надо уточнять у школьных педагогов, какое решение в текущий момент считается корректным (если это нужно для экзаменов).  В вузовской программе это структурные элементы, которые допускается считать союзными аналогами, но они не меняют вид предложения. Можно прочитать на эту тему короткую статью  https://proza.ru/2022/06/14/535 Но вопрос действительно спорный, пока однозначно он не решается.

Comment: На каком сайте можно посмотреть, чем является слово - союзом / союзным словом / самостоятельной частью речи? Нац корпусе?

Comment: И у Розенталя / Лобанина "поэтому" тоже является местоименным наречием? У РАН?

Comment: Точной информации я не могу вам указать, но мне кажется, что сейчас вряд ли можно найти единственно верное решение.  Розенталь - это справочник по правописанию, а не по грамматике, тем более современной.  Национальный корпус русского языка — крупнейшее электронное собрание ТЕКСТОВ, включающее более 500 млн словоупотреблений, один из основных источников, к которому обращаются лингвисты, исследующие русский язык.

Comment: А как задать вопрос от главного к придаточному предложению, которое вы написали? "Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль, ДЛЯ ЧЕГО были приглашены итальянские мастера".

Comment: Алексей, я отвечу вам чуть позже, сегодня у меня просто нет времени. И еще просьба: все вопросы лучше задавайте сразу, еще до принятия ответа. Потом приходится вспоминать тему, как бы снова погружаясь в нее. Ваши вопросы интересные, но не из простых, прямого ответа в учебниках часто нет. К тому же такой вопрос можно задать на форуме, и тогда вы услышите разные мнения, а это всегда лучше, чем одно.

Comment: Тогда задам вопрос, чтоб было проще)

Comment: Правильное решения! Я сразу отвечать не буду, послушаю другие ответы. Мне тоже интересно. Если не все скажут, тогда отвечу.